# Как запустить GridSearchCV на основе своей метрики оценки?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, numpy, scikit-learn, классификация

Двухклассовая классификация, `y`- цели, `x` - признаки, `weights` - веса.
Собственная метрика - сумма положительных значений весов при совпадении прогноза с реальностью.

Библиотеки:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import talib as ta
import xgboost
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```

Данные:

```
x = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(1000, 5))
y = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(1000, 1))
weights = np.random.randint(-100,100,size=(1000, 1))
```

Своя Метрика:

```
def my_score_func(y_true, y_pred):
    global weights
    return  weights[(y_pred==1) & (y_true==1) & (weights>=0)].sum()

my_scorer = make_scorer(my_score_func, greater_is_better=True)
```

Поиск по сетке:

```
XGB = xgboost.XGBClassifier()
param_grid = {'n_estimators': [20,30,50,80,100]}
XGBgs = GridSearchCV(XGB, param_grid, scoring = my_scorer, cv = 2) 
XGBgs.fit(x,  y)
```

Не получается настроить поиск по сетке на основе своей метрики.
Ошибка:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
>   (501,501) (1000,1)

Comment: ваша метрика совершенно не учитывает реальные значения `y` (`ground truth`) и соответственно модель не сможет обучаться... В подобных вопросах лучше всегда приводить небольшие примеры входных данных и то, что вы ожидаете получить на выходе (результат)

Comment: Ок, а в таком варианте?                                                                                                           'def summa_pos(y, y_pred, res):
    return res[y_pred==1 & y==1][res>=0].sum()'

Comment: Ok, а как на счет примеров данных - `y`, `y_pred` и `res` ? ;)

Comment: :) y =[1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1]  y_pred =[1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0] res =[12,0,0,130,0,0,0,0,0,41]

Comment: а как оценивать получившийся  `score` - чем больше тем лучше или наоборот?

Comment: :) greater_is_better=True

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
weights = res

def my_score_func(y_true, y_pred):
    global weights
    return weights[(y_pred==1) & (y_true==1) & (weights>=0)].sum()

my_scorer = make_scorer(my_score_func, greater_is_better=True)
```

**P.S.** [пример использования созданного `scorer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_multi_metric_evaluation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-multi-metric-evaluation-py)

---

или так (более предпочтительный вариант):

```
def my_score_func(y_true, y_pred, weights):
    return weights[(y_pred==1) & (y_true==1) & (weights>=0)].sum()

my_scorer = make_scorer(my_score_func, greater_is_better=True, weights=res)
```

Comment: выдает ошибку def __call__(self, clf, X, y, sample_weight=None):\n\nTypeError: my_score_func() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: Пыталась запустить XGB = xgboost.XGBClassifier()
XGBgs = GridSearchCV(XGB, param_grid, scoring = my_scorer)) 
XGBgs.fit(x,  y)

Comment: Можете объяснить что такое `res` и откуда оно берется?

Comment: Да. конечно. Это цена положительного ответа. Заранее известна вместе с метками. Метка 1. Веса от -150 до +150. Зависит от полезности сигнала

Comment: @АннаЛебедева, если цена известна заранее, то можно попробовать "хардкодировать" переменную `weights` - подправил ответ

Comment: спасибо, попробовала, просто метрику - считает. GridSearchCV с метрикой выдает ошибку. Исправила вопрос выше

Comment: @АннаЛебедева, мда, похоже так "в лоб" сделать не получится, т.к. `GridSearchCV()` - сам разбивает выборку на обучающую и тестовую случайным образом, поэтому не совсем понятно как ему подсунуть соответствующий вектор `res`

Comment: Тоже об этом подумала, судя по ошибке. В GridSearchCV через fit_params = {'sample_weight': weight}  можно подсунуть веса. Но я пока не поняла, как их передать в свою метрику :)